# Vote based approval system in DBMS

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I try to create a system to auto approve proposed posts by popular vote. I am currently evaluating what portions of this I can do within the DBMS and if it is sensible. I use PostgreSQL and I can go up to the newest version if that helps me.

My database structure would look somwhat like this:

```
CREATE TYPE state AS ENUM ('write', 'vote');

CREATE TABLE post
(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL CONSTRAINT post_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(100),
  state state
);

CREATE TABLE proposal
(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL CONSTRAINT proposal_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT proposal_post_fkey REFERENCES post,
  text TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE accepted
(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL CONSTRAINT accepted_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT accepted_post_fkey REFERENCES post,
  text TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE vote
(
  proposal_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT vote_proposal_fkey REFERENCES proposal,
  user_id INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY(proposal_id, user_ID)
);
```

[Here you can find a SQLFiddle for that layout](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dfc88/1)

My goal is now to build on or more queries to copy the proposal to accepted and set the state to write according to these rules:

1. If the number of votes for a proposal is more higher than a threshold n
2. If there is exactly one proposal with the highest vote count

My question is now whether this can sensibly be done within PostgreSQL or should be done outside and also if you could point me into the right direction for the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the votes are inserted one-by-one and not in bulk, then you can do what you want using a trigger on `votes`.

Basically, you when a vote is retrieved, the trigger would:

- Calculate the total number of votes for the proposal.
- Check if the total meets the threshold.  If so, then do what you want for "accept".

Personally, I would tweak your design.  Instead of an `accepted` table, I would simply have a flag in `proposals`.  I would also modify `proposals` to have the total number of votes.  And, I'm not clear on what or whether proposals are competing against each other -- that is, if one is accepted, does that preclude voting on others?

Also, you are unclear on what happens if votes are "removed" from a proposal.

Comment: Good points. For the sake of brevety I removed a component from all of this. They phases have a time span. The phases will only switch if the threshold of votes is reached. votes are not removed from proposal. They are kept for later. They votes indeed compete with each other. Therefore I have the problem that it is possible that at the time of the switch the number of votes for two proposals could be the same. I don't know how to filter that out in one query.